# MenuItem HorizontalAlignment not working

Tags: wpf, menu, menuitem

I have a menu inside the grid with on item:

[image]

I want to change the horizontal and vertical alignment of this MenuItem to fit the entire grid cell.

I wrote this:

```
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Menu>
```

But it stays as before:

[image]

I even tried to change the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center` and it's still the same. 
How do I accomplish this?

Note: the menu itself is stretched by default - you can see that because of the background color.

**update**

I need to support subItems. if I only put `MenuItem` without a `Menu` opening of sub items is not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have single `MenuItem` and want it to fill the parent panel, you don't need a `Menu`. This should work:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="200">
    <MenuItem Header="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

If you have a `Menu` that may contain several items, it doesn't make much sense for a single item to fill the available space.

Comment: Subitems don't work if I don't surround the MenuItem with a menu contorl

Comment: You didn't mention anything about sub items in your original question.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think it was necessary. I updated the question.

Comment: You should ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: It's the same issue. You solution is good but not sufficient.

Comment: It was until you change the question to a different one :)